# Block ping in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, icmp

I have deployed my Asp.Net web application  on **Windows Server 2008  R2 ,**    and I want to **block** all **ping** requests to this **server** without effecting  my **application** .

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't programming related - it's down to firewall, network edge technologies, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes i know its not programming related, well have developed and deploy my app on window server2008 r2 and for security purpose i need to block all  ping, Dont knw wheither its right place to ask this qstn ;)
thnx

Comment: That's why I've voted to close with a redirect to serverfault.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/22713  blocking ICMP isn't necessarily a great idea, it is used to make TCP/IP networking work properly.  Only a couple to a few of the ICMP protocols are actually a security problem, and ping isn't necessarily one of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to **Start** → **Administrative Tools** → **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security** → **Inbound Rules** → **File and Printer Sharing** (Echo Request – ICMPv4-IN) → right click and select **Enable Rule**.

My application now works fine and when I try to ping my server I do not receive any response.

Comment: This didn't work for me until I also changed that rule's setting from "Allow" to "Block the connection".

Answer (score 2):

Using the solution provided by Satinder, you should further refine the scope of which computer/server and/or IP range(s) can Ping your server.

That way, the public can't ping your server but maybe you or certain computer on your network can get to it in case you need a quick check on connectivity.

Comment: Do you understand that OP is Satinder, and he answered his own question?