# synchronizer - unable to get client-side resource

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

I already put this into the old forum so I hope this will be fine.

Suddenly in one location users to the CMS side now are getting errors. If they work elsewhere there is no problems. I know the forum usage is low but if I shall slap the network people silly I need to have some pointers.

User gets several errors during the loading homepage process.

Err 1: A few times: JavaScript alert - 
[synchronizer] unable to get client-side resource with ID xxxx

Err 2: Sometimes:
Unspecified error. on /library/javascript/mdvc.js

Err 3: several times:
A GUI system error occured. Details:[CmdsHTTPDone]

```
<tcmapi:Response xmlns:tcmapi="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/TCMAPI" success="false" actionWF="false" ID="WebGUIResponder.aspx"><tcmapi:Error><tcm:Line Cause="true"  mlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"><![CDATA[Request message cannot be empty. ]]></tcm:Line></tcmapi:Error></tcmapi:Response>
```

Err 4: Sometimes we also get "permission denied" errors on TaskBarControl.js or other scripts.

In the end.. all views empty.

When trying to use a web proxy tool (Fiddler2) to see what is sent/received; user do NOT get any problems. Can log in and use the CMS without any problems. As long as the local web proxy tool is used, user have no problems with the CMS. As soon as tool is shut down, same problems come back.

So using this tool, we cannot even debug as we don't know what impact fiddler has on the connection making it work. Just in one location for Prod and Test (same issues) but DEV still is fine.. so my deduction is.. "some rule in the local network" is wrong - but how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The CME GUI loaded in the browser reguarly checks back with the CME server. This looks like the browser cannot get a connection with the CME server.
For further troublehsooting you can try what happens if you do a full reload (CTRL-F5) of the web browser to see if it has a connection issue indeed.

If it is a connection issue it might not be Tridion related at all.

Comment: I don't think it is Tridion that is the problem, but how this particular office connects to it with the AD. (LDAP authentication and I have no problem). I do get partial CMS content in my IE. But the issue would be then "how" to present it to those scary network people. Something has started preventing a complete connection. The submarine hunters (Network team) will just do what they always do.. "PING - I get response - not a network issue" - I probably need to explain to them why/where.

Comment: I agree, just pinging is a very limited form of troubleshooting network issues. You could [block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260897/block-ping-in-windows-server-2008-r2) ICMP on your server so that the server will not reply to ping, that might make your network guys a bit more helpful ;)

Comment: Are you using any company proxy (so besides Fiddler)? We had a similar issue, turned out that the company proxy was having problems with an incorrect dns entry. Our clue at the time was the Firefox was working fine while IE and Chrome were not. And FF has its own proxy configuration while the other 2 both use IE's internet settings.

Comment: Sure we use a proxy.. ;) But "oh no - nothing has been changed" when asking.. to bad one cannot confirm the behavior as FF and Tridion2009 don't work. But I wonder what a proxy can do different for AD authentication vs LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a proxy issue -- especially since you say that you cannot reproduce it using Fiddler. Fiddler works by acting as a proxy, so that would explain the lack of symptoms when using it.

You can try just using your browser's developer tools (press F12). Then watch for any requests that come back with a different status code than 200 or 304. You can then show this to your network team who can hopefully troubleshoot the issue from there.